# Alternative to mathptmx

Tags: math-mode, fonts, times

In my documents I have always used the `mathptmx` package. [From what I read](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx), however, this is an obsolete package. I tried the `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` packages, but the output is different.

Could you recommend a more recent alternative to `mathptmx` package?

Comment: `newtxmath` is recommended _because_ the output is different. If you want exactly the same as `mathptmx`  then keep using that. You could try other Times-like clones, `\usepackage{stix2}` for example if you don't like newtxmath

Comment: Have you tried `newpxmath`?